# how to align image and label side by side in html?

Tags: html, css

[image: Look at the image]

I want my logo on the left side and navigation bar on the right side.
I tried img outside nav class and it did align to left but i want nav and my logo together. How do i do this? Thank you.

Here is my Code:

```css
.img {
  text-align: left;
  background-position: left;
}

.nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" height="40px" width="80px" style="margin-left: 5px; text-align: left;">
  <label for="toggle"> &#9776; </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Share</a>
    <a href="#">Useless</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Renove the text-align and background-position and add display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content) 1fr;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing the attached code, it will surely work but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

In this code I have have made a new `<div>` and added `float:left;` to it and removed some inline and internal CSS.

Your code was not getting the job done because you have added opposite properties to parent (`.nav`) element and child (`menu`) element.

```css
.img {
      float: left;
}
.nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
.menu{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nav</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="img">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" height="40px" width="80px" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <label for="toggle"> &#9776; </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <a href="#">Share</a>
            <a href="#">Useless</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JeetViramgame  I am so happy to hear that my solution worked for you and thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer, it means a lot to me. I hope I get more chances to assist you.

Comment: let's connect on social media. search jeetviramgama on twitter. and your most welcome.

Comment: @JeetViramgame Sorry I don't use twitter but we can connect on github. Check my profile for my github username. I would love to collaborate with you on some project.

Answer (score 2):

just use `float` to align content `left` or `right`

```css
.img {
      float: left;
}
.nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
.menu{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nav</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="img">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" height="40px" width="80px" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <label for="toggle"> &#9776; </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <a href="#">Share</a>
            <a href="#">Useless</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good solution. The checkbox (`#toggle`), I think, will be hidden by default.

```css
.img {
    text-align: left;
    background-position: left;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

.nav label {
  margin-right: auto;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
       
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" height="40px" width="80px" style="margin-left: 5px; text-align: left;">
        <label for="toggle"> &#9776; </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <a href="#">Share</a>
            <a href="#">Useless</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```